# UV Unwrapping - All Maps Ruined (distorted)

Tags: materials, uv, uv-image-editor

So I was unwrapping for some big portion of my day today and all of a sudden all the maps that I so carefully have been portioning have changed their dimensions - it basically looks like they were never unwrapped. All I can think of is just before this happened I marked some seams around a cluster of faces. Not satisfied, I deleted some of its edges and made it into one big face. After that all maps using the same material in my scene were ruined.
No other faces that use different materials were affected.
I first undid as many steps as I could without result. I force shut the software and started up the project - looked just the same so I assume there is no way of saving all this wasted time and work.
I'm just wondering what the heck happened. It's not the first time I've had this problem.
How do I make sure that this never happens again?

Thanks,
Samuel

Comment: Drop a screenshot, maybe your . blend file with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: You can make sure this doesn't happen again by pinning (shortcut key `P`) the vertices in your UV that are already in a place you like (and don't plan on moving).

Comment: Just have you checked File > Recove > Auto Save directory if there is not any undestroied? Also by default blender saves versions .blend1 .blend2 if you delete number it become regular file to open so there could be a chance?